# VARMA with t-student innovations

Tags: multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression, t-distribution

I'm wondering if there is a possibility to estimate VARMA model with t-student innovations in R. I found package MTS, but all models here seem to be estimated assuming multivariate normal distribution. Thanks for any help!